# SubSection support in .INI files

Tags: delphi, ini

Delphi's RTL has a tantalizing function: [`TCustomIniFile.ReadSubSections`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.IniFiles.TCustomIniFile.ReadSubSections)

But this doesn't really seem to be properly explained anywhere.

- How do you write subsections?
- How do subsections actually appear in the INI file?
- And, once you've called `ReadSubSections`, how do you use the result to read data from a particular subsection?

Comment: I think it only is implemented in TMemIniFile http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/IniFiles_TMemIniFile.html so you just can try to use it, and then read the ini file in notepad to check the formatting. But since it is TMemIniFile-only and non-standard, i'd refrain from using it. If you really need to use a storage structured in more than two layers - just use JSON SuperObject

Comment: @Arioch'The I don't see anything abut writing subsections in that page? Did I miss something...

Comment: well, not only. It also is implemented in registry. and that probably is where it came from. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Win.Registry.TRegistryIniFile.ReadSubSections so you ccan try to read from TRegistryIniFile to a temporary stringlist, then from the SL into TMEmIniFile, then save it to the ini-file and read it in notepad. I think the intention is to use SubSections name just instead of Sections names in Read*** and Write*** methods. And i blindly guess they would be written with back-slashes just like the regedit's ini-files with *.reg extension. But you do try

Comment: Again, rather than using non-standard non-documented extension to ini files i think it would make more sense to use standard JSON via some well-credited library (dbExpress is not)

Comment: @Arioch'The I'm considering JSON, but I'd like a comment mechanism (and for comments to be preserved if the config is modified by the application.)

Comment: For both INI and JSON there is the only reliable method of persisting comments to include them, as some keys with a special convention about their names. Or to only use read-only access. Both Windows (TIniFile) and Delphi (TMemInifile) implementations give no warranties about non-data and may overwrite file if they wish (and TMemIniFile would really do). So if you need comments either stick with XML, or meake a dedicated comment values

Comment: @downvoter - Anything particular wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

To write subsections just join your section name and subsection name with a backslash.

[section_name\subsection_name]

```
procedure Foo;
var
  LIniFile: TIniFile;
  slValues: TStringList;
  IniFileName: string;
begin
  IniFileName := ''; //your ini file
  LIniFile := TIniFile.Create(IniFileName);
  try
    //SECTION = MAINSECTION
    //SUBSECTIONS = SUBSECTION_A
    //            = SUBSECTION_B
    LIniFile.WriteString('MAINSECTION\SUBSECTION_A','IDENT','A');
    LIniFile.WriteString('MAINSECTION\SUBSECTION_B','IDENT','B');

    slValues := TStringList.Create;
    try
      LIniFile.ReadSubSections('MAINSECTION', slValues);
      //slValues.count = 2
      //slValues.strings[0] = SUBSECTION_A
      //slValues.strings[1] = SUBSECTION_B
      // do your stuff here!
    finally
      slValues.Free;
    end;
  finally
    LIniFile.Free;
  end;
end;
```

the ini file looks like:

```
[MAINSECTION\SUBSECTION_A]
IDENT=A
[MAINSECTION\SUBSECTION_B]
IDENT=B
```

Comment: The default section name separator is a backslash.

Comment: @UweRaabe Aye! i guessed that! TMemIniFile tries to mimic RegEdit.exe .reg files with cooperation with TRegIniFile :-D

Comment: @UweRaabe. I'd seen that - but the code posted works correctly. *Very* weird.

Comment: @UweRaabe yes, backslash is right separator. But for the example dot works. Anyway I'll correct the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @AgustinSeifert where there's no specifications, there are heuristics and error recovery :-) i think that is why there are a set of pre=hardcoded chars, each of those would be treated as a separator

Comment: The backslash separator is only relevant when you specify the Recurse parameter as True.

Comment: JFTR, it is **not** bound to TMemInifile only!

Comment: Actually it's worse than that, at least in D2010. If you use `ReadSubSections('MAIN', slValues)` in the above example you get `'ECTION.SUBSECTION_A'` and `'ECTION.SUBSECTION_B'`, so the separator is basically ignored!!!

Comment: @Roddy, yeah - this feature is simply not fully implemented. I wouldn't suggest to use it anyway.